# Android generate signed apk (release) with minifyEnabled true in observable.subscribe data = null

Tags: android, rxjava, retrofit2, proguard

После Generate Signed APK с установленным в gradle minifyEnabled true данные с сервера приходят (это видно по логам), но в onNext data = null.

```
     apiManager.getCities()
            .subscribe({
                if (it.data != null) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "response - onNext, data size: " + it.data.size)
                } else {
                    Log.i("TAG", "response - onNext, data is null ")
                }
            }, {
                Log.i("TAG", "response - load error: " + it.message)
            })
```

С помощью HttpLoggingInterceptor можно отследить загрузку данных.

В gradle minifyEnabled true
[image]

А вот результат, когда gradle minifyEnabled false.
[image]

В proguard-rules.pro ничего особенного:

```
    -dontwarn retrofit2.**
    -dontwarn okhttp3.**
    -dontwarn okio.**
```

Comment: Вероятно нужно прописать правила для Proguard для rxJava. Нашёл [вот такую библиотеку](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/RxJavaProGuardRules)

Comment: @eugeneek  в rxJava2.x не нужно это прописывать, поскольку там нет рефлексии. [ссылка на gitHub](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/RxJavaProGuardRules#note-about-rxjava-2x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил ошибку, добавил в proguard-rules.pro

```
    #your package path where your gson models are stored
    -keep class com.mypackage.example.entity.** { *; }
```